# "Unresolved Reference: Interpreter" error for Tensorflow Lite Interpreter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, tensorflow-lite

I am getting the error: "Unresolved reference: Interpreter" for the line

```
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter
```

My Gradle build is 3.2.1 and Android Studio version 3.4.2

Below is the App build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.tensorflow.lite.examples.posenet"
    minSdkVersion 27
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation project(":posenet")
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
  implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```